# How to @Inject A Bean into a Java Class?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am working on learning Spring and Java.  I created a Spring 3 app and tried to make a connection pool as a bean:

```
 @Bean
 public ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource() {

    ComboPooledDataSource pool = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    // configure here
 }
```

Then in another class:

```
public class DatabaseQuery {

@Inject private ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource;

private Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        return comboPooledDataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

From some debugging statements I can see the connection pool is successfully created, but when I use the comboPooledDataSource, I get a NullPointerException.  How to I get the bean and use it?  Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: how is the other class registered with spring?

Comment: Please show your Spring application context configuration, especially the classpath scanning section. In order for bean injection and autowiring to work you need to properly setup classpath scanning

Comment: Hi Gerry, I am configuring it the context programmatically, not using XML.  `@Configuration
public class ApplicationContextConfiguration { ...     @Bean
    public ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource pool = new ComboPooledDataSource();`

Comment: I would like to set up classpath scanning etc.  Is that something for the context setup?

Comment: Hi Gerry, the component scan is defined in my app config: `@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.company.app"})
public class ApplicationContextConfiguration {`

Comment: how did you get DatabaseQuery bean in your application?

Comment: Hi Alexander, I believe the solution is to use the @Named annotation from javax.inject.  See below.  I say believe because this exposed an unrelated issue in my database driver version, but it appeared to inject the bean successfully.  I'll have more information today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to explicitly access the Spring context

In AppConfig:

```
@Bean
public ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource() {
```

Then in the application

```
private Connection getConnection() {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationContextConfiguration.class);
    ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource = ctx.getBean(ComboPooledDataSource.class);
    try {
        return comboPooledDataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can also get it by name if you use the javax.inject @Named annotation:

```
ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource = ctx.getBean("myDataSource");
```

Then in AppConfig:

```
@Bean
@Named("myDataSource")
public ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource() {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring version 3.1 and higher - add annotation

```
@ComponentScan({"by.company.app"})
```

after `@Configuration` annotation

After that you must tell spring that your DatabaseQuery must be managed by spring. So add @Component before class declaration:

```
@Component
public class DatabaseQuery {
    // code
}
```

After that spring will manage both dataSource and query object and inject dataSource to query.

Comment: Hi there, I did what you specified but I still get the null pointer exception: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.company.app.DatabaseQuery.getConnection(DatabaseQuery.java:29) ~[App-0.1.0.jar:na]`

Comment: Line 29 is the call to getConnection()

Comment: First question (silly): did you specified your package in ComponentScan. Second question - are you sure that connection to db is working

Comment: In my app config `@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"my.company.app"})
public class ApplicationContextConfiguration {`  However the DatabaseQuery class is located in a sub package `my.company.app.data.sql`.  Do I need the full path?

Comment: Also yes, the connection appears good.  In my logs I have the pool firing up: `INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 2sfvk18w17usdfc1eosh7a|290c011f, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass ...`

Comment: No, you don't need to specify subpackage.

Comment: The NPE is coming from the call to getConnection, so I think I still didnt inject the actual bean.  What can I do next?

Comment: Yes, problem is here. It is interesting why spring doesn't injects bean... There is only one requirement to this - class must be annotated as Component or declared in xml or java configuration. Maybe try to create java-based configuration for Query bean: @Bean
 public DatabaseQuery databaseQuery() {
  return new DatabaseQuery(dataSource());
 }

Comment: OR! try to add also annotation @AnnotationDrivenConfig after Configuration

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35874/discussion-between-the-user-518469-and-david-williams)